# Searching by bitmask in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, bitmask

I have a users table with a bitmask field that has a permissions mask in it. Locally, I can determine whether a user has a certain permission by doing a bitmask `(UserPermissions&Perm)==Perm`. However, I want to be able to issue a `find_by_mask` or something similar, perhaps using a `:conditions`, but I can't seem to find out how I can query the database to retrieve a list of users with a matching permission mask.

Any ideas using ActiveRecord?

Specifically this must work using sqlite and postgres

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The sane thing to do, in my opinion, would be to break out your bitmask field into a series of boolean fields.  Storing bitmasks in a relational database is not that far off from storing delimited lists in a field -- it's borderline denormalization.

That said, you can use a bitwise AND in your SQL queries with the & operator, so you can say:

```
User.where('permissions & ? > 0', Perm)
```

Comment: Thanks for the bitwise info. I thought about using booleans, but I have some 15 permissions, and might add more later. Using a bitmask is much much cleaner than having 15+ booleans in the table.